# Generating Random Numbers for a Combat Simulator

Tags: python, function, class, random

I am attempting to create a very basic Combat Simulator. Here is my code:

```
import random
#from random import * I had, at one time, created a D20 generator that used the * function. I have since removed it in favor of using randint()
sword = 0
D20 = 0

class Hero:

    def swing_and_hit(sword, D20):

        sword = D20
        print(D20)
        if sword >= 10:
            print("You have defeated the Villian!")

        elif sword  < 10:
            print("You have died!")

D20 = randint(1,20)
Adventurer = Hero
#Adventurer.D20_Func()  Ignore this...aborted effort to try something
Adventurer.swing_and_hit(sword, D20)
```

Every time I run this at http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit, the random number generator outputs 13. I cannot figure out why it does this...any thoughts? I have tried nesting the random number generation inside the function swing_and_hit, and it still generates the same number every time I run the program.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do but this doesn't work. You have to do `random.randint` or `from random import *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a  "feature" in Pythontutor to ensure different people will see the same results running the same code.  (I am getting always 17)

Whether or not they define it as a feature, it is broken as it could be - random numbers should be random.

Just install Python in your own computer, and get going - it is a smaller than 20MB download from http://python.org if you are using Windows (and if you are not, you have Python installed already). There are interactive interpreters and even a simple development environment that is installed along with the language - there is no motive for you to hurt yourself with a web implementation that might be good for group study of some code, or introspecting what goes in each variable step by step. Python interactive environments are much more dynamic than the "click to run" you get on this site.

Answer (score 2):

I think the random number generator producing the same number every time is a quirk of [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com). I get 17 every time with just this code:

```
import random
print(random.randint(1, 20))
```

If you must use a website to run your code, try [repl.it](http://repl.it/languages/Python3).